# MIPS Assembly - Simple

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm currently asking myself how this works. Example: If I load a value into $t0 and then another in the next operation, do the old one gets aggregated with the new one or is the old one trashed and gone and the new one takes in place?

Example:

```
lw $t0, 15 # $t0 := 15
lw $t0, 8  # $t0 := 23 or 8?
```

Thanks in advance,
Klois.

Answer (score 0):

The old value gets replaced. If you want accumulation you have to explicitly say so by using an `add` instruction.

As a side note, you'd typically use `li` rather than `lw` to load an immediate value (or `ori`  if your assembler doesn't support pseudo-instructions).